# Recycling array of length 1 in array-vector arithmetic is deprecated. Optimization Sum of Squared Errors

Tags: r

I need to find the optimal weight (a) to minimize sum of squared errors. I use this as an example as I'll have a more complex problem to work on which requires the use of some other optimization packages but lm. I receive warnings() saying that "In a * y. Recycling array of length 1 in array-vector arithmetic is deprecated. Use c() or as.vector() instead." I tried as.vector(a * y), a[1] * y, a * as.vector(y) but nothing works.

What should I do to get rid of this message?

```
install.packages("NlcOptim")
library(NlcOptim)

x <- c(1:4)
y <- c(2,4,6,8)

objfun <- function(a) {
  return(sum((x-a*y)^2))
}
x0 <- 1
solnl(x0,objfun = objfun)
```

Here is the error message that I see after typing `warnings()`:

```
1: In a * y :
  Recycling array of length 1 in array-vector arithmetic is deprecated.
  Use c() or as.vector() instead.
```

Answer (score 2):

This is confusing indeed, but what you really need to do is, in fact, use `as.numeric`, like this:

```
return(sum((x-as.numeric(a)*y)^2))
```

doing R's job of interpreting a 1x1 array as a scalar. Not sure how as.vector() or c() would have ever been helpful.

Comment: Simple solution to a silly problem that shouldn't exist in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I would suggest to do nothing about it. R simply does not like to adding one dimensional arrays to numeric vectors.

```
x <- array(1, dim = 1);
x + c(1,1)

[1] 2 2

Warning message:
In x + c(1, 1) :
  Recycling array of length 1 in array-vector arithmetic is deprecated.
  Use c() or as.vector() instead.
```

As you can see, the result is correct, so you are pretty safe to ignore that warning.

Comment: @DSGym and if I want to get rid of the warning, how can I do that? I don't get the suggestion of using `c()` or `as.vector()`. I tried `c(x)+c(1,1)` but I got the same warning

Comment: use `as.vector(x)` for any array x

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but found your question when I tumbled into the same warning message. In your case, I think you need to treat `a` as a vector with `c(a)` or `as.vector(a)` inside your function `objfun`. (So you almost got it with your tries `as.vector(a * y)`, `a[1] * y` and `a * as.vector(y)`).

Thus:

```
install.packages("NlcOptim")
library(NlcOptim)

x <- c(1:4)
y <- c(2,4,6,8)

objfun <- function(a) {
  return(sum((x-c(a)*y)^2))
}
x0 <- 1
solnl(x0,objfun = objfun)
```

Running this code we obtain

```
$par
     [,1]
[1,]  0.5

$fn
[1] 5.913821e-15

$counts
     nfval ngval
[1,]    13     3

$lambda
$lambda$lower
     [,1]
[1,]    0

$lambda$upper
     [,1]
[1,]    0


$grad
             [,1]
[1,] 1.033147e-07

$hessian
     [,1]
[1,]  240

Warning message:
In cbind(LAMBDA, 0.5 * (LAMBDA + LAMBDA_old)) :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
```

I don't know what the last warning means, but it is into the package you are using.