# Use c() or as.vector() instead warning in R

Tags: r, warnings

Can anyone explain why I have following warning and how to fix it?

I cannot see why I have problems. It seems the final answer is correct.

```
#Creating variance and covariance matrix
c <- diag(0.5, nrow = 4)

c[lower.tri(c)] <- c(0.2, -0.3, 0.2, 0.5, -0.4, -0.7)

d <- c + t(c)

e <- c(10, 12, 5, 18)

f<- outer(e, e) * d

f
#Defining expected return
mu7 <- c(10, -15, -15, 13) 

#Define the value of lambda
labmda7 <- 0.8

#Define the benchmark portfolio weight
b7 <- c(0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1)

#Solving alpha7
i <- c(1, 1, 1, 1)
alpha <- ( t(i) %*% solve(f) %*% mu7) / (t(i) %*% solve(f) %*% i)
xstar7 <- (1 / labmda7) * solve(f) %*% (mu7 - alpha * i )

warning:
Warning in alpha * i :
  Recycling array of length 1 in array-vector arithmetic is deprecated.
  Use c() or as.vector() instead.
```

Comment: Recommendation: Do not use `c` as the name of an object, it is one of the base functions of R

Comment: neither of the r scolds have actually answered the question. it is because `length(i) > 1`, ie, `matrix(1) * 1:3` is a warning but `matrix(1) * 3` is not, in the first example, the array is recycled to the length of `i` whereas it does not need to be recycled in the second

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recycling array of length 1 in array-vector arithmetic is deprecated. Optimization Sum of Squared Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55884074/recycling-array-of-length-1-in-array-vector-arithmetic-is-deprecated-optimizati)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note: Don't override R functions, like `c`. I renamed them for you.**

You need to convert the arrays to vectors using `as.vector`.

#### Code:

```
x <- diag(0.5, nrow = 4)

x[lower.tri(x)] <- c(0.2, -0.3, 0.2, 0.5, -0.4, -0.7)

d <- x + t(x)

e <- c(10, 12, 5, 18)

f<- outer(e, e) * d

f
#Defining expected return
mu7 <- c(10, -15, -15, 13) 

#Define the value of lambda
labmda7 <- 0.8

#Define the benchmark portfolio weight
b7 <- c(0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1)

#Solving alpha7
i <- c(1, 1, 1, 1)
alpha <- ( t(i) %*% solve(f) %*% mu7) / (t(i) %*% solve(f) %*% i)
alpha <- as.vector(alpha)
xstar7 <- (1 / labmda7) * solve(f) %*% (mu7 - alpha * i )
```

Or replace the last two lines with:

```
xstar7 <- (1 / labmda7) * solve(f) %*% (mu7 - as.vector(alpha) * i )
```

As you can see I write `i <- as.vector(i)` also `alpha <- as.vector(alpha)`.

And now the output has no warning, output:

```
     [,1]  [,2] [,3]  [,4]
[1,]  100  24.0  -15  36.0
[2,]   24 144.0   30 -86.4
[3,]  -15  30.0   25 -63.0
[4,]   36 -86.4  -63 324.0
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Can I ask why we change ```as.vector()```, then everything works.

Comment: @MathildaFang Well, it's because R will disallow adding arrays to vectors in the future, it will only let adding vectors to vectors in the future versions. It's better to do that already now to remove the habit of adding arrays to vectors so that there will be less confusion in future versions.

Comment: @MathildaFang It's also mentioned [here](https://github.com/GLEON/rLakeAnalyzer/issues/75) on GitHub :)

Answer (score 1):

This warning is given because `alpha` is a matrix in your last line.

```
xstar7 <- (1 / labmda7) * solve(f) %*% (mu7 - as.vector(alpha) * i )
```

If you transform in a vector it will not an error.